# Simpliest solution to a circular image in android?

Tags: android, imageview

In iOs to make an ImageView appear circular all I would really have to do is this:

```
itemPhoto.layer.cornerRadius = itemPhoto.frame.size.height / 2;
itemPhoto.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Is there a simple solution like so for Android? I did research but found several methods that seemed slightly different from one another and seemed pretty lengthy for a beginner like myself. This will be for a ListView, and will scale each photo in the ListView, so performance is a must. Even a link to a GOOD reference would be fine!

Answer (score 1):

I've had success just importing a library such as this one https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView. You just have to add this line to your dependencies in build.gradle:

`compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'`

Answer (score 0):

In the latest support library you can use [RoundedBitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html) to create a drawable of your image then you pass that into your imageview